# How to POST to a specific URL using the Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: c#, .net-core, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to send a POST request to the following URL using the MS Graph Client.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SiteID}/lists/Documents/contentTypes/addCopyFromContentTypeHub](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BSiteID%7D/lists/Documents/contentTypes/addCopyFromContentTypeHub)

I looked at the various Request Builders and didn't see anything for "addCopyFromContentTypehub". There's a "ContentTypeAddCopyRequestBuilder", but that's a different action.

I tried getting access to the graph client's HttpProvider, but I can't figure out how to send the authentication with the request.

```
var requestUrl = graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Lists["Documents"].ContentTypes.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("addCopyFromContentTypeHub");
var contentTypeId = "<ID>";
var body = $"{{\"contentTypeId\": \"{contentTypeId}\"}}";

using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl))
{
   httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(requestUrl, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
//Errors here
var result = await graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
};
```

There error I get is:
"MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call."

My graph client uses an Azure AD App Registration to make all the calls so I need to include ".WithAppOnly()" on all my requests, but I don't see a way to do that using graphServiceClient.HttpProvider

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate `HttpRequestMessage` through Graph client

```
await graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

Code:

```
using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl))
{
   httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(requestUrl, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   await graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(httpRequestMessage);
   var result = await graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
};
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but I get the same "MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call."